# Adding hours in each columns in fullcalendar.js

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I would like to add the time into each cell of fullcalendar, regardless the number of ressources I have.

I don't really know how to process. I uploaded a picture with what I would like.

Thanks a lot!

[image: What I have]

[image: What I would like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
The idea is to add background events.
"15" is your timeslot, in the following example with 60 minutes

in event function add (with arbitrary star_day and end_day)

```
 events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
   var timeCursor = moment(start_day);
   while (timeCursor < moment(end_day))
   {
     events.push({
      start: timeCursor.toISOString(),
      color:"inherit",
      title:timeCursor.utc().format("HH:mm"),
      end: timeCursor.add('15', 'minutes').toISOString(),
      rendering: 'background'
      });
    }
  }
```

in eventRender function add:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
 if (event.rendering == 'background') {
  element.append(event.title);
  }
 }
```

Here is the result (with 60 minutes):

[image]

Comment: Can you guide me what to do if I want to add/append columns to only last row?